# Swipe to refresh layout problem when used with custom behavior

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` which contains a view with a custom `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` (item_search_button) and a `SwipeRefreshLayout` containing a `NestedScrollView`.
The custom view is a button which should scroll out of the screen with the normal scrolling but should appear (scroll from top) as soon as the user scrolls up the list. This works as expected.
My problem is that the refresh indicator of the `SwipeRefreshLayout` appears behind the custom view item_search_button.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_startpage"
        app:snackbar="@{offlineSnackbarVM.snackbarData}">

        <include
            layout="@layout/item_search_button"
            app:vm="@{searchButtonVM}"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:refreshing="@{reloadVM.refreshInProgress}">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nestedView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/elementsContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_48"/>

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

item_search_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data class="SearchButtonBinding">

    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="vm.SearchButtonVM"/>

</data>
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="behaviors.ScrollSnapBehavior"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_8"
    android:onClick="@{() -> vm.openSearch()}">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/leftIcon"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

[image]

But I want it before the item.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem with a workaround by

1. Using onScrollListener to check if the list is scolled at top and
   set `translationX` if it is on top to let the indicator paint over
   the cardview.
2. Using `setProgressViewOffset()` to increase the offset and paint it
   below the cardview to avoid a nasty flicker effect.

Works for me...

Answer (score 1):

`CardView` has a default elevation which makes it appear above the `RecyclerView` although it is the first child in the `CoordinatorLayout` (see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout) for a description of how `CoordinatorLayout` works). To have the `CardView` disappear below the list/ the progress indicator while refreshing, you can temporarily set its elevation to zero and reset it once the refresh has finished.

Let's assume you have a dimension resource for the elevation in *res/values/dimens.xml*

```
<dimen name="cardview_elevation">4dp</dimen>
```

Then you can set the elevation programmatically.

Java version:

```
float normalElevationInPixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.cardview_elevation);
myCardView.setCardElevation(normalElevationInPixels);
```

Kotlin version:

```
val normalElevationInPixels = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.cardview_elevation)
myCardView.cardElevation = normalElevationInPixels
```

Comment: Good hint with the card elevation. However, my first try was to modify the translationZ of the SwipeRefreshView and the search item view. Worked great at the first sight, without changing the shadows like elevation, but then I realized that the item was not clickable anymore. Then I used a combination of ScrollListener and OnTouchListener to determine the best moment to modify tranlationZ, but I did not achieve good results. (for example, the refresh indicator was overlayed for a part of a second and then popped up in the foreground, which does not look very nice)...